# Airflow DAG triggers, but fails to execute tasks

Tags: airflow

I recently set up Airflow for a local project. So far, the tasks created in my DAGs do not run, even if the DAGS themselves appear to have.

An MRE is provided beneath.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

# Set default arguments
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 1, 1),  # Set a fixed start_date in the past or current time
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=30)
}

# Set schedule
dag = DAG(
    'basics',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Test Airflow',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup=True
)

# Define operators
hello_world = BashOperator(
    task_id='hello_world',
    bash_command='echo "hello world" >> ~/PycharmProjects/san_francisco_311/airflow/logs/hello_world.txt',
    dag=dag
)

print_date = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='echo {{ ds }}',
    dag=dag
)

# Set dependencies
hello_world >> print_date
```

I would expect running this graph to log the file hello_world.txt.

Instead, I get the following terminal output...

```
[2023-08-03T14:52:57.729+0200] {__init__.py:42} INFO - Loaded API auth backend: airflow.api.auth.backend.session
     |        |                  | data_interval_en | data_interval_st |          |                  | last_scheduling_ |                  |          |            |       
conf | dag_id | dag_run_id       | d                | art              | end_date | external_trigger | decision         | logical_date     | run_type | start_date | state 
=====+========+==================+==================+==================+==========+==================+==================+==================+==========+============+=======
{}   | basics | manual__2023-08- | 2023-08-02T00:00 | 2023-08-03T00:00 | None     | True             | None             | 2023-08-03T12:52 | manual   | None       | queued
     |        | 03T12:52:57+00:0 | :00+00:00        | :00+00:00        |          |                  |                  | :57+00:00        |          |            |       
     |        | 0                |                  |                  |          |                  |                  |                  |          |            |
```

...and the file is not logged.

According to airflow configs list, the DAG folder is set up correctly (nor would I expect to get the result above if it were not). The variable catchup does not affect the outcome if changed between True and False.

Comment: check in the ui if the DAG is paused? new dags by default are paused